# Convert UTC to IST using C#

Tags: c#, timezone, utc

I have tried to convert a Specific UTC time into IST time. But, I got the same date as the output.

**// utcdate is 6/15/2014 12:00:00 AM**

```
var istdate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcdate,
              TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```

**Output :6/15/2014 12:00:00 AM**

Could you please guide me to resolve this issue?

Comment: that should work fine. are you sure the original is utc

Comment: @Jon yes that is original UTC. But getting the same date

Comment: how are you retireving that UTC?

Comment: that's directly from Azure Database

Comment: @Ponmalar: did you try mu solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try This:

```
DateTime utcdate = DateTime.ParseExact("6/15/2014 12:00:00 AM", "M/dd/yyyy 
                                       h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var istdate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcdate,
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```

I'm getting output :

```
6/15/2014 5:30:00 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
        DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(new DateTime(2014, 6, 16, 2, 0, 0));
        DateTime temp = new DateTime(utc.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime ist = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(temp, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```